# Best practice of RestAngular

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

So I've started to work on an own project, where I'm in the middle of developing the front-end of my website. I started out with an PHP Laravel back-end and I've setted up an API service for my database.

With a hybrid app in mind, i started using angularjs for my front-end web application. For the communication with my API using REST, I've came across restangular, which is pretty nice because it was exactly what I hoped for.

There is only one issue that bothers me, there is no real "guide" how to setup a maintainable module/factory/provider/service to replicate your api with a system that stores the data in local storage or setup simple system where you could inject the "Model" into an controller and just do `Model->getAll()` to fetching all models.

Because I'm new to angularJS, and therefor my knowedge on how to appeach this, is fairly limited. So far I've made this:

main application

```
var client = angular.module('clientApp', ['angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics', 'ngRoute', 'restangular']);

client.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'flongsController',
            templateUrl: '/client_partials/Homepage.html'
        })
        .when('/flongs/:slug', {
            controller: 'flongsController',
            templateUrl: 'client_partials/Flong.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

flongsController

```
client.controller('flongsController', ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$routeParams', function ($scope, Restangular, $routeParams) {
    //controller variables
    var baseFlongs = Restangular.all('flongs');

    $scope.flongs = {};

    init();

    function init() {
        baseFlongs.getList().then(function(flongs){
            $scope.flongs = flongs;
        });
    }

}]);
```

So, my question is simple:

How can i improve this code so that its more efficient and more maintainable?

Thanks in advance,
Nick van der Meij

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all do not use service logic on the controller, instead use angular services for this purpose.

Let me share you how I build my projects,

First build **Restangular Service** :

```
angular.module('example').factory('exampleService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular){

    // this is service object with list of methods in it
    // this object will be used by controller
    var service = {
        getExamples: getExamples,
        getExample: getExample
    };

    // get examples from server by using Restangular
    function getExamples(){
        return Restangular.all('examples').getList();
    }

    // get example with given id from server by using Restangular
    function getExample(exampleId){
        return Restangular.one('examples', exampleId).get();
    }

    return service;

}]);
```

here we build **exampleService** now let's inject it into a controller

```
angular.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['exampleService', function(exampleService){

    // get examples by using exampleService
    exampleService.getExamples().then(function (examples) {
        $scope.examples = examples;
    });

    // get example with given id by using exampleService
    exampleService.getExample('1234').then(function (example) {
        $scope.example = example;
    });

}]);
```

This is how I use it basically. For more advanced usage you can look the examples in [Restangular Github Page](http://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

Comment: I'm looking at the design pattern of restangular and have a question regarding your statement. "First of all do not use service logic on controller" > Do you not think that Restangular itself is in some sense providiing this service logic, and in your example all you are doing is proxying / creating another abstract layer on top of the Restangular functionality?

Comment: @Blowsie I know this is old but I'm having the same question and I'm torn between the alternatives. Using Restangular as is would work but at the same time would tie my whole app and all of the controllers to Restangular. On the other hand, creating a factory and proxying all calls would add an (unnecesary?) abstract layer on top of Restangular. Is it too bad to add this extra layer in sake of better abstraction?

Comment: @tomidelucca I actually ditched restangular and ended up using ngResource, with a very lightweight abstract layer for that http://pastebin.com/54bp2nQC